# Same java applet on multiplite .aspx page gives error "already loaded in another classloader"

Tags: java, asp.net, applet

I'm using java applet in my ASP.NET application. I have mastrepage and multiply .aspx pages based on it. In masterpage I have

```
<applet
    codebase="~/_LAYOUTS/ARM_EPO/JAR/"
    code="com.iit.certificateAuthority.endUser.libraries.signJava.EndUser.class"
    cache_archive="EUSignJava.jar"
    cache_version="1.3.65"
    archive="EUSignJava.jar"
    id="euSign"
    width="100%"
    height="0">
</applet>
```

Fuctionality of this applet is needed to use at all .aspx pages of application. Loaing on first page is ok, but when I'm loading another page, java gives me an error

**java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native Library C:\Users\o.besarab\AppData\Local\Temp\EUSign-x86-1.3.65\EUSignJava.dll already loaded in another classloader**

Applet's functionality made by another company. Is this error shows because I'm using same applet in different pages? Or what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Use param separate_jvm.

```
<applet
    codebase="~/_LAYOUTS/ARM_EPO/JAR/"
    code="com.iit.certificateAuthority.endUser.libraries.signJava.EndUser.class"
    cache_archive="EUSignJava.jar"
    cache_version="1.3.65"
    archive="EUSignJava.jar"
    id="euSign"
    width="100%"
    height="0">
    <param name="separate_jvm" value="true">
</applet>
```